# setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil when returning objects from Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I am returning a number of objects from my Parse class to a UITableView. I'm getting this error when I try to open the view:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: $in)
```

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
@implementation MessageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self refresh];

    _favorited = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
}

- (void)refresh {

    NSArray *favorite_ids = [PFUser currentUser][@"favorites"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:favorite_ids];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *projects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MoreMessages"];
        [query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:favorite_ids];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *companies, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }

            [_favorited setArray:[projects arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:companies]];
            NSLog(@"%@", _favorited);
            [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        }];

    }];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (_favorited.count < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return self.favorited.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_favorited.count < 0) {
        return 127;
    }
    return 65;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (_favorited.count < 0) {
        NoFavoritesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NoFavoritesTableViewCell"];
        return cell;
    }

    MessagesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessagesTableViewCell"];

    _favoritedObject = [_favorited objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [(PFFile*)_favoritedObject[@"profilePic"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }];

    cell.name.text = _favoritedObject[@"name"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Maybe try debugging the code to see what line it dies on and what variable is nil at the time?

Comment: Try displaying Projects & Companies arrays.. Companies is getting nil I think..Check it by debugging the code..!

Comment: Please add an exception breakpoint, run it, and update the question (or just add defensive code around the null column).  Without taking this or @PhillipMills advice, this question qualifies for a close under "why is this code not working".

Answer (score 0):

All the null parse values must be set to `[NSNull null]` and will be received as `[NSNull null]`.

It is inconvenience on many levels as you should check for every single level if it is `[NSNull null]` or not. I use 2 convenience methods:

```
- (id)nsNullOrObject:(id)object
{
    if(object == nil)
    {
        return [NSNull null];
    }
    else
    {
        return object;
    }
}
- (id)objectOrNil:(id)object
{
    if(object == [NSNull null])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        return object;
    }
}
```

The first is used when assigning a value to a Parse object and the second when receiving the value from the Parse object.